# Default constructor creation time & multiple definitions

Tags: c++

As far as I know , default constructors are created when needed.
means actually, that the compiler actually creates it only when it needs to be invoked.

Lets say I have two files , f.c and g.c and both of them have object creation code which requires aa default constructor. how does the compiler prevent creating multiple default constructors..? how does it "know" to create only ONE ? even though I use it in two files and didn't implement it my self.

My prof. told me that it has something to do with inline and told me to check about it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (*and most likely your professor*) misunderstand.
In C++ you can declare a function as many times as you like but there can be one and only one definition for that function. This is simplistic definition of the ***[One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule)***. Even if you create objects in two separate translation units. The constructor which compiler calls for object creation is defined only once.

So to answer your question,
*How does it know to create only ONE?*
It is programmed to create one and only definition, because it needs to comply to the one definition rule defined by the C++ standard.

Exception to one definition rule is, inline functions. inline functions are allowed to have multiple definitions provided all the definitions are exactly the same.

Comment: Does the compiler then define the default constructor it creates as INLINE by default?

Comment: @Rouki: It is an implementation detail. The compiler may generate multiple definitions and use inlining or it might just define a single definition, it will most commonly be the latter, since it is more logical and efficient way.